# Safe Mode for Batch Insert

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

When I use safe mode (journaling only) on a batch insert on a sharded cluster, the result comes back as a List of SafeModeResult on the C# driver (I assume it is similar on other drivers too). What does each result in the list mean?

Is it per item in the batch or is it per shard or is it per message sent to the sever?

Is batch insert atomic or not specially on a sharded environment? if not, how can do I know which portion of my batch has failed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The InsertBatch method in the C# driver does in fact attempt to send all the documents to the server in one message. However, there is a limit to the message length, which is approximately 16MB. So if the batch you provide InsertBatch is very large then InsertBatch might have to break it up into sub-batches in order to not exceed the maximum message length. When that happens you will get a separate SafeModeResult for each sub-batch, but normally you would expect the list of SafeModeResults returned to contain only one SafeModeResult.

Comment: sub-batch in around 4MB solve my problem but the performance of C# driver is slow

Answer (score 1):

That's actually not how it is with other drivers and I can't think of a good reason why it'd return a write result per insert for an actual batch insert since that defeats the purpose/optimization of the batch insert (which is seen as one operation by MongoDB and therefore only requires one getLastError() call).

How an actual batch insert works is that the batch insert is executed by MongoDB without the driver performing a getLastError() call per insert. This has the obvious downside that you can't see if an insert succeeded except for the last one in the batch (in the case of ContinueOnError = false) or the if any of them failed (in the case of ContinueOnError = true, in which case the actual error relates to the last failed insert).

It would seem that the C# driver method for batch inserts you're using is actually a convenience method that does do insert/getLastError pairs for each insert. That works just fine and tells you exactly which insert failed but it is therefore not an actual batch insert and does not take advantage of the optimization.

Batch inserts are not atomic. They're simply an optimization to reduce getLastError() overhead.

Comment: Are you saying the server insert batch could fail an item the middle without telling us as it only reports on the last item. That seems very dangerous where I could never trust if my full batch have been inserted. Am I getting your point right?

Comment: No, if it fails in the middle with ContinueOnError = false then it will stop, as such the failed item will be the last item and the error related to that item.